# implement Generator with class

Tags: python, class, oop, generator

I am trying to write a generator with class thats gets a list of numbers and, for each number, return `true` if the sum of the divisors of this number is greater than the number and `false` if not.
`sum_of_divisor_helper` is a helper function.
Unfortunately I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 33, in
>
> for i in numbers:   File "main.py", line 23, in **next**
> if (sum_of_divisor_helper(self.list1[self.x]) == True): NameError: name 'sum_of_divisor_helper' is not defined

This is the code:

```
class sum_of:
    
    def __init__(self,myList):
        self.x = 0
        self.list1 = myList
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
        
    def sum_of_divisor_helper(self):
        sum_of_divisors = 0
        for i in range(1, self.x):
            if self.x % i == 0:
                sum_of_divisors = sum_of_divisors + i
            else:
                pass
            if sum_of_divisors >= self.x:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        
    def __next__(self):
        if sum_of_divisor_helper(self.list1[self.x]) == True:
            return True
            self.x  = self.x + 1
        elif sum_of_divisor_helper(self.list1[self.x]) == False:
            return False
        else:
           raise StopIteration

numbers = sum_of([12,20,10,30])
for i in numbers:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Generators are special functions. You mean an iterator (a broader term). See the glossary: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.sum_of_divisor_helper(self.list1[self.x])
```

instead of

```
sum_of_divisor_helper(self.list1[self.x])
```

Use the `self` prefix when you're referring to a method inside of your class.

Comment: now I am getting those: Type Error: sum_of_divisor_helper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  @cesebe27

Comment: you should encounter your argument with parameter. Add   def sum_of_divisor_helper(self,varriable_name): for pass parameter

Comment: all the errors gone any idea why I am not getting the prints? its not print any true or false as I try  @cesebe27

Comment: well you have 2 for loops, but the loop you used in your main function is makes things unclear.The for loop you used in  sum_of_divisor_helper can do what you want to obtain, you iter all numbers when in every tour of loop.(You do all work at every step in main function loop). You can simply add print(True) above of the return True and do the same for return False